# Making a nav link look better with vertical alignment CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My question has two parts.

1. The most important part - I would like to vertically align the arrow next to that heading. On the left image (how it is now) you can see it is bottom aligned and doesn't look very nice.
2. (optional) This is a more broad question which I figured I'd throw in seeing I need help with the first part anyway... is there anything I can do to make that arrow and heading look better? Maybe a different font, or some other text tricks that would make it look nicer? Something about how it looks now just seems bland to me but I'm not sure how I can improve it.

Here is my code (the base theme is bootstrap):

```
<h3>
    <small><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></small> HEADING
</h3>

<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
    <span>This is an example of a text information box that will appear towards the top of the page.</span>
</div>
```

Here's the visual guide:

[image: Example]

Cheers

Comment: Wrap the content of the heading by an inline-level wrapper like `<span>` and apply `vertical-align: middle` to the children of the heading: http://jsbin.com/wecoju/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

```
<h3>
<small><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></small> <span>HEADING</span>
</h3>
```

add css

```
h3 span {
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a line of text that doesnt stretch over multiple lines, and you have a fixed height of your parent element.

Than you can set the **line-height** value of the text to equal the height of the parent container. Which will center your text on the y axis.

**Vertical-align middle** can only be used on for example table cells.

Else you can use a flexbox and set the **align-items: center;** property on the parent element for y axis and **justify-content: center;** for x axis.